# Montreal on public transport: what kind of tickets to use?

Tags: public-transport, tickets, montreal

For a 3-4 day visit in Montreal, what would be the most convenient & cost-effective way to use the city's public transit system?

Single tickets, some kind of day travelcard, or something else?

Also, are the same tickets valid on the metro and buses?

(Context: sightseeing, general wandering around, some nightlife. Accommodation downtown, near the Berri-UQAM station.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get 1- or 3 day (tourist) passes. More at http://www.stm.info/English/tarification/a-1a3jours.htm . We used them a couple of years ago - they worked just as advertised.

Comment: Thanks! The [prices](http://www.stm.info/English/tarification/a-grilletarif.htm) seem pretty good too: $8 for 1-day and $16 for 3-day card.